# Linkserver update not working in Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to do operation on my linked server
created one linked server  , everything is ok 
just observed one thing which I am not able to understand

if I run

```
 update SERVER.testdb.[AAA].MyTable
set MyName= 'abc@pqr.com'
where ID=999
```

This works fine ,but 
when i execute same code  in following way

```
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TRF

    update SERVER.testdb.[AAA].MyTable
    set MyName= 'abc@pqr.com'
    where ID=999


    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH     
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TRF

END CATCH
```

It shows The parameter is incorrect

Can anyone tell me why this is hapeening and what is solution ?

Comment: can you provide the exact error shown

Comment: OLE DB provider "SERVER" for linked server "LINKEDSERVER" returned message "The parameter is incorrect.".

Comment: Maybe you should use `BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION`?

Comment: No its still shows same error

Comment: Have you tried without transaction name `TRF`? And where is `COMMIT TRAN`?

Comment: Did you check the [settings for distributed transactions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60858/how-can-i-enable-distributed-transactions-for-a-linked-server)?

Comment: all those are not working